# Sharepoint authentication with local host works, but machine name does not work

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010

I have a remote connection with server machine. I log in server machine as administrator, open Internet Explorer. If I type both **localhost** and **machine name** site works . When I log in as another user and type **localhost** site works. But when I type the **machine name**, authentication page comes and when I choose either windows or form authentication nothing happens.

I need to work with **machine name** otherwise when I try to reach some pages such as approval page I get critical error.

Thank you

Comment: When I checked IIS logs, I find **Timer_ConnectionIdle**. I dont know if that make sense...

Comment: You should explicitly check the http status and http sub status values. You may find these values. And please, also describe what kind of authentication did you set up.

Comment: I set up windows authentication. Here is what I get: ** 2013-01-14 08:02:10 fe80::a900:2f78:ef02:6409%14 53468 fe80::a900:2f78:ef02:6409%14 32843 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -

Comment: this does not look like a complete [W3C IIS log format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754702.aspx), setup by sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication page has a simple JavaScript function which  blocks all sites, except Trusted Sites. You need to add "machine name" to trusted sites list in Internet Explorer to activate that JS function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your System Name is not known in DNS; your remote connection works because the system name is known. When you try to access from the outside it's not.

There is a very quick way to check this; on a connection that DOES NOT WORK, open the Hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) - add the entry: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemanme - for example, 10.0.0.20 MySystem. Save the file then open a command window - ping the server name and it should respond. Try the connection again and you should be OK.

The long-term fix is to talk to the system administrator to find out why the system name is not known on the network (often it can be because only the fully qualified domain name is known).